# Cleaning out Agar from Autoclave Reservoir

Tags: sterilisation

I have a Tuttnauer EZ10 autoclave where the previous user poured m-Endo Agar into the reservoir. Using vinegar, we've been able to remove most of it, but there is a thin film of purple residue coating the interior walls. To get the autoclave safely working again, would you recommend I 1) pour water in and do a steam cycle, or 2) buy the Tuttnauer Chamber Brite and use it?

P.S. I can't make an agar, autoclave, reservoir, maintenance, or cleaning tag, so would someone please make those too?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did any get down in the water drain pipe?

Comment: Hi CKM, yes it's in there too. What next steps would you recommend? 

We have got the agar out of the interior walls of the central chamber, but you can see the agar residue in the water reservoir container. Some vinegar we poured into that chamber has gotten a majority of it in the water reservoir, but we are interested in getting it as clean as possible before use.


And thank you so much for taking the time to help use resolve this issue!

Comment: So I had a floor-standing Hayama HV-50 autoclave when this happened, so I'm not sure how different the process must be, just to preface. We had to actually lock-out/tag-out our device, take the side covers off and disassemble the copper drain piping. Then we took what was essentially a plumbing snake and snaked the agar out of the drain pipe. Running a hot cycle and things like chemicals and boiling water didn't work well for us because down in the piping, the contact surface area at any given time is the thin diameter of the pipe. You could have 8+ inches of agar noodle in there.

Comment: It might be prudent to just get field service done on your device so you don't inadvertently void the warranty or permanently damage the device.

Comment: Hi CKM, sorry for the late response, thank you for your advice and suggestions! We'll look into doing field service like you recommended. Have a great day!